# 10X Illumina demultiplexing sample sheet issue

Tags: scrnaseq, 10x-genomics

Also posted [on biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/308123/).

I am trying to use `cellranger` or `bcl2fastq` to convert the `.bcl` files that I got from single cell analysis run into `fastq` files for further analysis. I needed to generate `sample_sheet.csv` and so I used the following tool:

https://support.10xgenomics.com/single-cell-gene-expression/software/pipelines/latest/using/bcl2fastq-direct

which I copy-pasted into a text file using `vim`. `sample_sheet.csv` looks like that:

```
[Header]
EMFileVersion,4


[Reads]
26
8
98

[Data]
Lane,Sample_ID,Sample_Name,index,Sample_Project
1,SI-GA-B4_1,17R,ACTTCATA,Chromium_20180406
1,SI-GA-B4_2,17R,GAGATGAC,Chromium_20180406
1,SI-GA-B4_3,17R,TGCCGTGG,Chromium_20180406
1,SI-GA-B4_4,17R,CTAGACCT,Chromium_20180406
1,SI-GA-B5_1,19RL,AATAATGG,Chromium_20180406 
1,SI-GA-B5_2,19RL,CCAGGGCA,Chromium_20180406
1,SI-GA-B5_3,19RL,TGCCTCAT,Chromium_20180406
1,SI-GA-B5_4,19RL,GTGTCATC,Chromium_20180406
2,SI-GA-B4_1,17R,ACTTCATA,Chromium_20180406
2,SI-GA-B4_2,17R,GAGATGAC,Chromium_20180406
2,SI-GA-B4_3,17R,TGCCGTGG,Chromium_20180406
2,SI-GA-B4_4,17R,CTAGACCT,Chromium_20180406
2,SI-GA-B5_1,19RL,AATAATGG,Chromium_20180406
2,SI-GA-B5_2,19RL,CCAGGGCA,Chromium_20180406
2,SI-GA-B5_3,19RL,TGCCTCAT,Chromium_20180406
2,SI-GA-B5_4,19RL,GTGTCATC,Chromium_20180406
3,SI-GA-B4_1,17R,ACTTCATA,Chromium_20180406
3,SI-GA-B4_2,17R,GAGATGAC,Chromium_20180406
3,SI-GA-B4_3,17R,TGCCGTGG,Chromium_20180406
3,SI-GA-B4_4,17R,CTAGACCT,Chromium_20180406
3,SI-GA-B5_1,19RL,AATAATGG,Chromium_20180406
3,SI-GA-B5_2,19RL,CCAGGGCA,Chromium_20180406
3,SI-GA-B5_3,19RL,TGCCTCAT,Chromium_20180406
3,SI-GA-B5_4,19RL,GTGTCATC,Chromium_20180406
4,SI-GA-B4_1,17R,ACTTCATA,Chromium_20180406
4,SI-GA-B4_2,17R,GAGATGAC,Chromium_20180406
4,SI-GA-B4_3,17R,TGCCGTGG,Chromium_20180406
4,SI-GA-B4_4,17R,CTAGACCT,Chromium_20180406
4,SI-GA-B5_1,19RL,AATAATGG,Chromium_20180406
4,SI-GA-B5_2,19RL,CCAGGGCA,Chromium_20180406
4,SI-GA-B5_3,19RL,TGCCTCAT,Chromium_20180406
```

Then I ran `cellranger` using `bash` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

 FLOWCELL_DIR="/scratch/nv4e/kipnis/180403_NB501830_0158_AHN3LLBGX5"
 OUTPUT_DIR="/scratch/nv4e/kipnis/fastq"
 SAMPLE_SHEET_PATH="/scratch/nv4e/kipnis/sample_sheet_2.csv"

cellranger mkfastq --id="AHN3LLBGX5" --run=${FLOWCELL_DIR} --csv=${SAMPLE_SHEET_PATH} --output-dir=${OUTPUT_DIR}
```

It fails with the following output:

[image]

`_stderr` file shows:

[image]

and that my `sample_sheet.csv` can not be parsed:

[image]

It could be because `CLRF` needs to be converted into `LF`, but I tried two commands to do this unsuccessfully:

`tr -d '\r' < input > output` and `perl -pi -e 's/\r\n/\n/g' input`

From the following thread:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277217/how-to-install-dos2unix-on-linux-without-root-access

The above commands successfully strip the `\r` from the line endings, but the error from bcl2fastq remains.

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

> Update

I looked into the folder that is generated when the `cellranger` runs and found two `.csv` files generated by the `cellranger`. One of them, `samplesheet.csv`, contains these `^M` characters that are shown in the error:

[image]

> Update

Maybe one of the issues was that I was submitting regular `.sh` file on the `SLURM` cluster. However, I wrote the right `.slurm` file and submitted it yesterday with `sbatch` command:

[image]

However, today I got the message in my email:

[image]

And neither `_stderr`, nor `generate_fastq_id.err` or `generate_fastq_id.out` files contain anything. I thought initially that I set not enough time and it timed out, however, it is not true: I set the time to `24h` and it has been running for just `13h` before failing.

> Update

I searched over all of the files in the generated folder with the `find` linux command and actually found the error files that show the same error as before: issue with the `sample_sheet.csv` file. This error file is `AHN3LLBGX5/MAKE_FASTQS_CS/MAKE_FASTQS/BCL2FASTQ_WITH_SAMPLESHEET/fork0/chnk0-u179acba3d8/_stderr`.

So, right now the issue seems to be the following: I am feeding in the right `sample_sheet.csv` without the `^M` symbols, but `cellranger` transforms it into one that contains `^M` and then uses it giving the error. Above I see also `which: no configureBclToFastq.pl` and `ERROR: bcl2fastq::common::Exception: 2018-Apr-09 13:33:14: Inappropriate ioctl for device`, so maybe my input parameters are just wrong to `cellranger` and it has nothing to do with the `sample_sheet.csv`?

> Update

I tried to use `--sample-sheet` instead of `--csv` since I am feeding in complex sample sheet. No luck.

> Update

Here you can find all the error document in text:

> which: no configureBclToFastq.pl in (/sfs/lustre/scratch/nv4e/cellranger/samtools_new/1.6:/sfs/lustre/scratch/nv4e/cellranger/cellranger-tiny-fastq/1.2.0:/sfs/lustre/scratch/nv4e/cellranger/cellranger-tiny-ref/1.2.0:/sfs/lustre/scratch/nv4e/cellranger/miniconda-cr-cs/4.3.21-miniconda-cr-cs-c9/bin:/sfs/lustre/scratch/nv4e/cellranger/cellranger-cs/2.1.1/lib/bin:/sfs/lustre/scratch/nv4e/cellranger/cellranger-cs/2.1.1/tenkit/lib/bin:/sfs/lustre/scratch/nv4e/cellranger/cellranger-cs/2.1.1/tenkit/bin:/sfs/lustre/scratch/nv4e/cellranger/cellranger-cs/2.1.1/bin:/sfs/lustre/scratch/nv4e/cellranger/lz4/v1.8.0:/sfs/lustre/scratch/nv4e/cellranger/martian-cs/2.3.2/bin:/sfs/lustre/scratch/nv4e/cellranger/STAR/5dda596:/sfs/lustre/scratch/nv4e/cellranger/samtools_new/1.6:/sfs/lustre/scratch/nv4e/cellranger/cellranger-tiny-fastq/1.2.0:/sfs/lustre/scratch/nv4e/cellranger/cellranger-tiny-ref/1.2.0:/sfs/lustre/scratch/nv4e/cellranger/miniconda-cr-cs/4.3.21-miniconda-cr-cs-c9/bin:/sfs/lustre/scratch/nv4e/cellranger/cellranger-cs/2.1.1/lib/bin:/sfs/lustre/scratch/nv4e/cellranger/cellranger-cs/2.1.1/tenkit/lib/bin:/sfs/lustre/scratch/nv4e/cellranger/cellranger-cs/2.1.1/tenkit/bin:/sfs/lustre/scratch/nv4e/cellranger/cellranger-cs/2.1.1/bin:/sfs/lustre/scratch/nv4e/cellranger/lz4/v1.8.0:/sfs/lustre/scratch/nv4e/cellranger/martian-cs/2.3.2/bin:/sfs/lustre/scratch/nv4e/cellranger/STAR/5dda596:/scratch/nv4e/cellranger:/scratch/nv4e/bcl2fastq/build/bin:/scratch/nv4e/spark/bin:/scratch/nv4e/scala/bin:/sfs/nfs/blue/nv4e/private/bin:/sfs/nfs/blue/nv4e/anaconda2/bin:/sfs/nfs/blue/nv4e/.local/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/slurm/current/bin:/opt/slurm/current/sbin:/opt/singularity/current/bin:/opt/rci/bin:/opt/rci/sbin:/opt/nhc/current/sbin:/share/rci_apps/common/bin:/share/resources/HPCtools/)
>   BCL to FASTQ file converter
>   bcl2fastq v2.20.0.422
>   Copyright (c) 2007-2017 Illumina, Inc.
>   2018-04-09 18:31:29 [7fcdb39f37c0] Command-line invocation: bcl2fastq --minimum-trimmed-read-length 8 --mask-short-adapter-reads 8 --create-fastq-for-index-reads --ignore-missing-positions --ignore-missing-filter --ignore-missing-bcls --use-bases-mask=Y26,I8,Y98 -R /scratch/nv4e/kipnis/180403_NB501830_0158_AHN3LLBGX5 --output-dir=/scratch/nv4e/kipnis/AHN3LLBGX5/MAKE_FASTQS_CS/MAKE_FASTQS/BCL2FASTQ_WITH_SAMPLESHEET/fork0/chnk0-u21f1cbe9bf/files/fastq_path --interop-dir=/scratch/nv4e/kipnis/AHN3LLBGX5/MAKE_FASTQS_CS/MAKE_FASTQS/BCL2FASTQ_WITH_SAMPLESHEET/fork0/chnk0-u21f1cbe9bf/files/interop_path --sample-sheet=/scratch/nv4e/kipnis/AHN3LLBGX5/MAKE_FASTQS_CS/MAKE_FASTQS/PREPARE_SAMPLESHEET/fork0/chnk0-u09e7cbe891/files/samplesheet.csv -p 6 -r 6 -w 6
>   2018-04-09 18:31:29 [7fcdb39f37c0] INFO: Minimum log level: INFO
>   2018-04-09 18:31:29 [7fcdb39f37c0] INFO: Sample sheet: '/scratch/nv4e/kipnis/AHN3LLBGX5/MAKE_FASTQS_CS/MAKE_FASTQS/PREPARE_SAMPLESHEET/fork0/chnk0-u09e7cbe891/files/samplesheet.csv'
>   2018-04-09 18:31:29 [7fcdb39f37c0] ERROR: bcl2fastq::common::Exception: 2018-Apr-09 18:31:29: Inappropriate ioctl for device (25): /scratch/nv4e/bcl2fastq/src/cxx/include/common/CsvGrammar.hpp(92): Throw in function bcl2fastq::common::CsvGrammarAttribute bcl2fastq::common::parseCsvData(Iterator, Iterator) [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; bcl2fastq::common::CsvGrammarAttribute = std::vector > >]
>   Dynamic exception type: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl
>   std::exception::what: Could not parse the CSV stream text:
>    ^M
>   ^M
>   [Reads]^M
>   26^M
>   98^M
>    ^M
>   ^M
>   [Data]^M
>   Lane,Sample_ID,Sample_Name,index,Sample_Project,Original_Sample_ID^M
>   1,SI-GA-B4_1,17R,ACTTCATA,Chromium_20180409,SI-GA-B4_1^M
>   1,SI-GA-B4_2,17R,GAGATGAC,Chromium_20180409,SI-GA-B4_2^M
>   1,SI-GA-B4_3,17R,TGCCGTGG,Chromium_20180409,SI-GA-B4_3^M
>   1,SI-GA-B4_4,17R,CTAGACCT,Chromium_20180409,SI-GA-B4_4^M
>   1,SI-GA-B5_1,19RL,AATAATGG,Chromium_20180409,SI-GA-B5_1^M
>   1,SI-GA-B5_2,19RL,CCAGGGCA,Chromium_20180409,SI-GA-B5_2^M
>   1,SI-GA-B5_3,19RL,TGCCTCAT,Chromium_20180409,SI-GA-B5_3^M
>   1,SI-GA-B5_4,19RL,GTGTCATC,Chromium_20180409,SI-GA-B5_4^M
>   2,SI-GA-B4_1,17R,ACTTCATA,Chromium_20180409,SI-GA-B4_1^M
>   2,SI-GA-B4_2,17R,GAGATGAC,Chromium_20180409,SI-GA-B4_2^M
>   2,SI-GA-B4_3,17R,TGCCGTGG,Chromium_20180409,SI-GA-B4_3^M
>   2,SI-GA-B4_4,17R,CTAGACCT,Chromium_20180409,SI-GA-B4_4^M
>   2,SI-GA-B5_1,19RL,AATAATGG,Chromium_20180409,SI-GA-B5_1^M
>   2,SI-GA-B5_2,19RL,CCAGGGCA,Chromium_20180409,SI-GA-B5_2^M
>   2,SI-GA-B5_3,19RL,TGCCTCAT,Chromium_20180409,SI-GA-B5_3^M
>   2,SI-GA-B5_4,19RL,GTGTCATC,Chromium_20180409,SI-GA-B5_4^M
>   3,SI-GA-B4_1,17R,ACTTCATA,Chromium_20180409,SI-GA-B4_1^M
>   3,SI-GA-B4_2,17R,GAGATGAC,Chromium_20180409,SI-GA-B4_2^M
>   3,SI-GA-B4_3,17R,TGCCGTGG,Chromium_20180409,SI-GA-B4_3^M
>   3,SI-GA-B4_4,17R,CTAGACCT,Chromium_20180409,SI-GA-B4_4^M
>   3,SI-GA-B5_1,19RL,AATAATGG,Chromium_20180409,SI-GA-B5_1^M
>   3,SI-GA-B5_2,19RL,CCAGGGCA,Chromium_20180409,SI-GA-B5_2^M
>   3,SI-GA-B5_3,19RL,TGCCTCAT,Chromium_20180409,SI-GA-B5_3^M
>   3,SI-GA-B5_4,19RL,GTGTCATC,Chromium_20180409,SI-GA-B5_4^M
>   4,SI-GA-B4_1,17R,ACTTCATA,Chromium_20180409,SI-GA-B4_1^M
>   4,SI-GA-B4_2,17R,GAGATGAC,Chromium_20180409,SI-GA-B4_2^M
>   4,SI-GA-B4_3,17R,TGCCGTGG,Chromium_20180409,SI-GA-B4_3^M
>   4,SI-GA-B4_4,17R,CTAGACCT,Chromium_20180409,SI-GA-B4_4^M
>   4,SI-GA-B5_1,19RL,AATAATGG,Chromium_20180409,SI-GA-B5_1^M
>   4,SI-GA-B5_2,19RL,CCAGGGCA,Chromium_20180409,SI-GA-B5_2^M
>   4,SI-GA-B5_3,19RL,TGCCTCAT,Chromium_20180409,SI-GA-B5_3^M
>   4,SI-GA-B5_4,19RL,GTGTCATC,Chromium_20180409,SI-GA-B5_4^M

Comment: What happens if you remove the duplicate emtpy lines (just keep one before each section)?

Comment: There are no duplicate lines in the input file, but inside the generated `_stderr` file they are somehow present

Comment: Is that the output from `_stderr` after removing `\r`? Because the `^M` characters indicate a line break problem. If they go away after running the `tr`/`perl` command, then there's probably an additional problem

Comment: Yes, it is after fixing the sample sheet.

Comment: Did you manage to install the configureBclToFastq.pl in the path as reported in the _stderr? BTW, if you make your error message as text it would be easier for us to search and quote specific parts of the error: CTRL+SHIFT+C and CTRL+SHIFT+V in terminal

Comment: No, I have not yet tried installing it because I do not know how. Could you give any links of how to do that and where to get the file?

Comment: There's no reason to install the old bcl2fastq (the configureBclToFastq.pl that's mentioned). Can you directly run `bcl2fastq` with your sample sheet (i.e., without using cellranger)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, we figured it out. If you delete everything until the `[Data]` tag in the sample sheet, leaving the `[Data]` tag, it starts working. Here is the full `sample_sheet.csv` that is working:

```
[Data]
Lane,Sample_ID,Sample_Name,index,Sample_Project
1,SI-GA-B4_1,17R,ACTTCATA,Chromium_20180409
1,SI-GA-B4_2,17R,GAGATGAC,Chromium_20180409
1,SI-GA-B4_3,17R,TGCCGTGG,Chromium_20180409
1,SI-GA-B4_4,17R,CTAGACCT,Chromium_20180409
1,SI-GA-B5_1,19RL,AATAATGG,Chromium_20180409
1,SI-GA-B5_2,19RL,CCAGGGCA,Chromium_20180409
1,SI-GA-B5_3,19RL,TGCCTCAT,Chromium_20180409
1,SI-GA-B5_4,19RL,GTGTCATC,Chromium_20180409
2,SI-GA-B4_1,17R,ACTTCATA,Chromium_20180409
2,SI-GA-B4_2,17R,GAGATGAC,Chromium_20180409
2,SI-GA-B4_3,17R,TGCCGTGG,Chromium_20180409
2,SI-GA-B4_4,17R,CTAGACCT,Chromium_20180409
2,SI-GA-B5_1,19RL,AATAATGG,Chromium_20180409
2,SI-GA-B5_2,19RL,CCAGGGCA,Chromium_20180409
2,SI-GA-B5_3,19RL,TGCCTCAT,Chromium_20180409
2,SI-GA-B5_4,19RL,GTGTCATC,Chromium_20180409
3,SI-GA-B4_1,17R,ACTTCATA,Chromium_20180409
3,SI-GA-B4_2,17R,GAGATGAC,Chromium_20180409
3,SI-GA-B4_3,17R,TGCCGTGG,Chromium_20180409
3,SI-GA-B4_4,17R,CTAGACCT,Chromium_20180409
3,SI-GA-B5_1,19RL,AATAATGG,Chromium_20180409
3,SI-GA-B5_2,19RL,CCAGGGCA,Chromium_20180409
3,SI-GA-B5_3,19RL,TGCCTCAT,Chromium_20180409
3,SI-GA-B5_4,19RL,GTGTCATC,Chromium_20180409
4,SI-GA-B4_1,17R,ACTTCATA,Chromium_20180409
4,SI-GA-B4_2,17R,GAGATGAC,Chromium_20180409
4,SI-GA-B4_3,17R,TGCCGTGG,Chromium_20180409
4,SI-GA-B4_4,17R,CTAGACCT,Chromium_20180409
4,SI-GA-B5_1,19RL,AATAATGG,Chromium_20180409
4,SI-GA-B5_2,19RL,CCAGGGCA,Chromium_20180409
4,SI-GA-B5_3,19RL,TGCCTCAT,Chromium_20180409
4,SI-GA-B5_4,19RL,GTGTCATC,Chromium_20180409
```

It is very unfortunate and disappointing that `10X` website is generating wrong sample sheet. Still we got very low mapping rates and trying to figure out what went wrong.

> Update

I was supplying `--sample-sheet=` property, but it should be `--samplesheet=`. Now it is running fine (except for very low mapping rates) with all the headers on.

> Update

It turned out that we were given the wrong indexes, so we made a sample sheet using sample sheet generator again and even with `--samplesheet=` correct parameter it was not running. Convertion of `CLRF` with `perl` or `tr` did not help. However, concise format of the sample sheet worked out well which looks like the following:

```
Lane,Sample,Index
1-4,17R,SI-GA-B8
1-4,19RL,SI-GA-B9
```

It needs to be supplied with `--csv=` parameter.

Comment: I found that if you copy and paste the 10X sheet directly from their website it inserts some odd characters on some of the blank lines.  I usually edit the file in vim and delete them.

Comment: Related to @GWW, I suspect it was the ` ^M` lines (the ones with a space and then line end). Either way, I suggest that you email 10x support and report this issue. It should be easy for them to fix.

Comment: It looks like it's a weird unicode character "U+00A0" / NO-BREAK SPACE.

Comment: That's weird. I copied and pasted from their website and never had issues. But I also run `mac2unix`/`dos2unix` on every sample sheet, so maybe that is a sufficient fix.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from supporting only Windows-style and Linux-style line endings and a restricted character set as mentioned above, the sample sheet [has to be in the correct encoding which is UTF-8](https://www.illumina.com/content/dam/illumina-marketing/documents/products/technotes/sequencing-sheet-format-specifications-technical-note-970-2017-004.pdf) (or its subset US-ASCII).
Many command lines support these [lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805418/how-to-find-encoding-of-a-file-via-script-on-linux) and [conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets) commands:

```bash
# lookup
file -i my_sample_sheet.csv

# conversion
iconv -f ISO-8859-15 -t UTF-8 in.csv > out.csv
```